# Controllers Not Calling Action

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework

i have a controller name UserController in application/controllers

the base folder is zend-login and there are 3 sub folder 1= application 2 = library 3=web_root
problem is here!! when ever i hit http://localhost/zend_login/web_root/user/login or  http://localhost/zend_login/web_root/user/register
i get this error Error 404  Object not found! both the file are there in a folder

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
public function indexAction(){
$this->view->assign('name', 'xainee');
$this->view->assign('title', 'Hello');
}
public function loginAction(){
$request = $this->getRequest();  
$this->view->assign('action', $request->getParam());  
$this->view->assign('title', 'Login Form');
$this->view->assign('username', 'User Name');   
$this->view->assign('password', 'Password');
}

public function registerAction(){
$request = $this->getRequest();
$this->view->assign('action',"process");
$this->view->assign('title','Member Registration');
$this->view->assign('label_fname','First Name');
$this->view->assign('label_lname','Last Name'); 
$this->view->assign('label_uname','User Name'); 
$this->view->assign('label_pass','Password');
$this->view->assign('label_submit','Register');     
$this->view->assign('description','Please enter this form completely:');
}
}
 ?>


action for this is here views/scripts/user/register.phtml and 
views/scripts/user/login.phtml 
this is register.phtml

<?php include "header.phtml"; ?>
<h1><?=$this->escape($this->title);?></h1>
<div id="description">
<?=$this->escape($this->description);?>
 </div>
<form name="register" method="post" action="<?=$this->escape($this->action)?>">
<table>
<tr>
 <td><?=$this->escape($this->label_fname)?></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?=$this->escape($this->label_lname)?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td><?=$this->escape($this->label_uname)?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user_name"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td><?=$this->escape($this->label_pass)?></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>   
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?=$this->escape($this->label_submit);?>">
</form>
<?php include "footer.phtml"; ?>
```

Comment: **i am new to zend framework so please dont mind my awkward question**

Comment: Could you please paste the complete error message?

Comment: @Songo problem solved i hit like this http://localhost/zend_login/web_root/index.php/user/register and it renders but i dont want index.php cox its in core php .i though zend will do it and in tutorials its like this which is not working

Comment: You can consider adding a virtual host to simplify things. It's actually recommended by Zend developers themselves.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function hasPluginResource() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend_login\application\controllers\ErrorController.php on line 67

Comment: Have you created a Bootstrap file ?

Comment: @Songo certainly its '<?php  
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);  
ini_set('display_errors', true);  
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');  
$rootDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));  
set_include_path($rootDir . '/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());  
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Front.php';
Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/controllers');  
?>'

Comment: Actually the file I meant was the one mentioned here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap

Comment: @shaheenbarki, what is the content of your `.htaccess` file under `webroot`?

Comment: @boosis 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php'

Comment: recommended .htaccess is `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: @boosis can u plz tell me what it will do ?? i mean whats the function of this code ?? how it will effect my application .thanQ

Comment: @shaheenbarki this code redirects all requests to your index.php if the resource doesn't exists. i.e. if you have a `test.html` file in your `web_root`, user will still be able to access it via `http://domain.com/test.html`, but if requested resource doesn't exists, user will be redirected to index.php and this should hide `index.php`

Comment: just place paste it in your `.htaccess` file under `web_root` and give it a go

Comment: @boosis thanQ very much for you info. i am new to zend and i am getting help so thanQ..

Comment: @shaheenbarki no problem at all. I added my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommended .htaccess is 
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`